# What is the performance overhead for fseek?

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel, kernel

Is there any performance overhead of `fseek`? E.g., does a `fseek` call actually asks the kernel to move disk head?

Also, does `fseek` performance cost have anything to do with how "far" it seeks? E.g., fseek(1byte) v.s. fseek(100Mb) v.s. fseek(end-of-file).

Comment: It really depends on the underlying layers. Filesystem, physical medium etc. Actually it doesn't have to do anything except changing some number in memory. The actual read/write afterwards is the one making the difference.

Comment: It is most probably negligible, an independent of seeking distance, but you are not going to receive any definitive answer. The best you can do is measure it yourself, and even then, you have no guarantees that what you will measure on your system is going to be anywhere near what you would measure in another system. (But it will most probably be universally negligible. Irrespective of distance.)

Comment: On almost all types of devices, the overhead is negligible.

Comment: Surely the disk head will only be moved for an *actual read* that is not already buffered / cached. Why would the disk head move if you issue several `fseek` instructions without actually reading?

Comment: There is an implicit cost to `fseek()` calls - any buffer associated with the affected `FILE *` will likely be flushed if the `FILE *` is in write mode, or invalidated if in read mode.  IO patterns such as random small reads will likely result in significant extra read overhead as the buffer gets refilled for each `fseek()`/read cycle.  The "distance" of the `fseek()` and the performance impact might matter or it might not. It will depend page cache hits and on how far the disk head(s) have to move.  Which can vary depending on many, many things.

Comment: *"does a fseek call actually asks the kernel to move disk head?"* -- That would be illogical.  The disks are accessed by many users and processes.  Unless every other access were locked out, any seek by one process without a read or write operation would probably be a waste of time.  Besides, **current versions of ATAPI have deprecated the seek command**.  A seek can only be implied in a read or write command.

Answer (score 1):

As always, the **only** way to know how things affect performance is to test it. But here are some general statements:

> Is there any performance overhead of fseek?

*Everything* has a performance overhead. Most things only have a small performance overhead. If you call `fseek` and the kernel or library has read ahead (read more of the file than you asked for yet) then it'll most likely throw away the read-ahead data since it's for the wrong location.

> E.g., does a fseek call actually asks the kernel to move disk head?

No it does not. It just updates the place that the kernel will read from the next time you read from the file. The hard drive won't do anything until you read from the file.

The disk head may or may not have to move the next time you access the file. But it might have to move *anyway*, even if you don't use `fseek`, because the file might be fragmented or because another program accessed a different file on a different part of the disk.

It could work the other way too. If the part of the file that you're seeking to happens to be in the cache (because something accessed it before), the kernel can get it from the cache instead of having to access the hard drive at all.

Of course head movement is irrelevant for SSDs, or files in tmpfs, etc.

> Also, does fseek performance cost have anything to do with how "far" it seeks? E.g., fseek(1byte) v.s. fseek(100Mb) v.s. fseek(end-of-file).

Probably not much.

Comment: *It just updates the place that the kernel will read from the next time you read from the file.* It might not even do that much in read mode if the target location of the `fseek()` call is within any user-space cache holding already-read data associated with the `FILE *`.